# When we receive packets from an UDP server, why do we have to receive them in a seperate thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking, udp

So my application is a very simple. If you type something through the scanner it sends it over to the server, the server sends it back to client. However, i don't understand why we have to put our code where we handle our receiving packets from the server into a thread?

The code below works fine but if i don't use use multithreading then the application doesn't work. The part where i send packets also stop working. Could you explain why this happens?

```
public class Client {

private static DatagramSocket socket = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Send to server:");

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true) {

        try {
            // port shoudn't be the same as in TCP but the port in the datagram packet must
            // be the same!
            socket = new DatagramSocket();
        } catch (SocketException e1) {
            System.out.println("[CLIENT] Unable to initiate DatagramSocket");
        }

        InetAddress ip = null;

        try {
            ip = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("[CLIENT] Unable to determine server IP");
        }

        // must be in a while loop so we can continuously send messages to server
        String message = null;

        Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                receive();
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            message = scanner.nextLine();

            byte[] buffer = message.getBytes();

            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, ip, 6066);

            try {
                socket.send(packet);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("[CLIENT] Unable to send packet to server");
            }
        }

    }

}

private static void receive() {
    
    // receiving from server

    byte[] buffer2 = new byte[100];

    DatagramPacket ps = new DatagramPacket(buffer2, buffer2.length);

    while (true) {
        try {
            socket.receive(ps);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("[CLIENT] Unable to receive packets from server.");
        }

        System.out.println("[SERVER] " + new String(ps.getData()));

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You don't. But `DatagramSocket` I/O operations are blocking, so whatever thread you run them on may block doing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you type something through the scanner it sends it over to the
> server, the server sends it back to client.

So the main method runs on the main thread and does some job. The job that you just referenced.

Read some user input plus the following part

```
 while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            message = scanner.nextLine();

            byte[] buffer = message.getBytes();

            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, ip, 6066);

            try {
                socket.send(packet);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("[CLIENT] Unable to send packet to server");
            }
        }
```

> Title: receive packets from an UDP server

You want to receive packets but you don't want to block the user from typing something as input and sending it to the server.

Therefore you need to do 2 jobs simultaneously. AKA multithreading

Comment: No, no, no. What i meant: Why does the client not work when we don't make use of this beautefull concept called "MuLtItHrEaDiNg"

Comment: Your explanation is very understandable sir.